# Oracle error occur when l try to connecte as sysdba: Credential retrieval failed

Tags: oracle11g

Hello guys l always have this error "ORA-12638: Credential retrieval failed" when l try to connect in my oracle database as sysdba
Who can help me?

My sqlnet.ora content:

```
# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to include your `sqlnet.ora` file?

Comment: it's done I added the contents of my sqlnet.ora file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have NTS authentication in your sqlnet.ora file.
Replace:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
```

With:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NONE)
```

[Source](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12638_credential_retrieval_failed.htm)

Comment: I changed the sqlnet file as you said but when I did that I log in as idle bundle